# How can I permanently save Metadata to a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exif

I want to save a UIImage to my Photo Library with metadata. I am able to save it already, but my metadata will not save as well. Any help? (btw, I am reading the metadata using http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi) My code:

Saving:

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

//MARK: - Add image to Library
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Adding metadata:

```
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    let jpeg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    var source: CGImageSource? = nil
    source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((jpeg as CFData?)!, nil)
    let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source!, 0, nil) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
    var metadataAsMutable = metadata
    var EXIFDictionary = (metadataAsMutable?[(kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String)]) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
    var GPSDictionary = (metadataAsMutable?[(kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String)]) as? [AnyHashable: Any]

    if !(EXIFDictionary != nil) {
        EXIFDictionary = [AnyHashable: Any]()
    }
    if !(GPSDictionary != nil) {
        GPSDictionary = [AnyHashable: Any]()
    }

    GPSDictionary![(kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude as String)] = 3.14
    GPSDictionary![(kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude as String)] = 3.14

    let UTI: CFString = CGImageSourceGetType(source!)!
    let dest_data = NSMutableData()
    let destination: CGImageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(dest_data as CFMutableData, UTI, 1, nil)!
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source!, 0, (metadataAsMutable as CFDictionary?))
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be obtaining the metadata and attaching it to `dest_data` (impossible to tell from here whether you are doing that successfully), but the problem is that you are not then saving `dest_data` into the photo library. You need to throw away your use of the outmoded UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, and instead use the Photos library: create a PHAssetCreationRequest for your asset and call `addResource(with:data:options)`.